# Array index out of bounds error under Icecream Sandwich but not 2.3.5

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a listView which is loaded via a custom cursuror from a SQL database. It is used to delete items from the main list in a different activity. Each row has a check box beside it and when the check box for a row is ticked a hidden delete button appears in that row, when the user clicks the delete button that row is removed.

On my HTC Desire HD running 2.3.5 this works perfectly and I have no issues however on my friends phones, a Galaxy Note and S3, running Ice cream sandwhich an error occurs.
On the phones running icecream sandwhich if they check the checkbox of every row and then click the delete button of the last row, the app crashes with an *arrayIndexOutOfBounds* error.
The error occurs in this block

```
if ( isChecked )
                {
                   // Make deleteButton appear 
                   RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) buttonView.getParent();
                   deleteButton = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
                   checked[position] = 1;
                   deleteButton.setVisibility(0);
                }
```

at this line: `checked[position] = 1;` on line 98.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening?

The error log is below and my code below that.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
at com.Roardog.FidelrFull.DeleteCampaignCustomCursorAdapater$1.onCheckedChanged(DeleteCampaignCustomCursorAdapater.java:98)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:140)
at com.Roardog.FidelrFull.DeleteCampaignCustomCursorAdapater.getView(DeleteCampaignCustomCursorAdapater.java:86)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2403)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1251)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12912)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12912)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12912)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12912)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2264)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12912)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1271)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2678)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
    public class DeleteCampaignCustomCursorAdapater extends CursorAdapter {

protected static final String TAG = null;
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Activity context;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
protected ListView mListView;

private Cursor c;
public static int[] checked;

TextView merchantNameView;
Button deleteButton;
CheckBox selectForDelete;
//ImageView moveButton;

public DeleteCampaignCustomCursorAdapater(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    this.context = (Activity) context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.c = c;
    c.moveToFirst();
    initializeChecked();
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {     

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_campaign_row_layout, null);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); //Create Roboto font       

    c.moveToPosition(position);

    myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); //Links to DatabaseHelper class

    if (convertView == null) {
        mInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_campaign_row_layout, null);
    }       

    merchantNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteMerchantNameView);
    deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    selectForDelete = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteCheckBox);     

    merchantNameView.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("merchantName")));
    merchantNameView.setTypeface(tf);
    merchantNameView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    final int  rowID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    if (checked[position] == 0) {
        selectForDelete.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        selectForDelete.setChecked(true);
    }

    selectForDelete.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( isChecked )
            {
               // Make deleteButton appear 
               RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) buttonView.getParent();
               deleteButton = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
               checked[position] = 1;
               deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                //Hide deleteButton
                RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) buttonView.getParent();
                deleteButton = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
                //checked[position] = 1;
                deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(rowID > 0) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Button Click. rowID = "+rowID);                   

                myDbHelper.deleteRecordWithID(rowID); //Call deleteRecord on selected row
                c.requery(); //requery the cursor
                notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the view the data set has changed 
                initializeChecked();  // re-set the checked array
            }                           
        }
    });

    return convertView;     
}

public void initializeChecked() {
    checked = new int[c.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < c.getCount()) {
        checked[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It'd be cool if i shouldn't count to line 98... So can you please write which on it is?

Comment: Sorry, done. I've highlighted the block of code the error occurs in and the actual line itself.

Comment: Sorry can't see it on this. Have you tried debugging it? Else how did you defined checked ? Also its bad codestyle to do .setVisibility(0), should use .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Can't see the line where the error occurs or can't see why it is occuring? Checked is defined at the top of the class as `public static int[] checked;`